# netstat cannot find opened port by iptables

Tags: networking, netstat

My Linux command is following:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5002 -j ACCEPT
iptables-save
netstat -natp
```

but the result of `netstat` has no item about 5002.

Comment: With this `iptables` command, you accept traffic for port 5002. `netstat -a` lists socket. Since there is no socket for port 5002, neither a listening socket nor an established one, it doesn't show you anything. If you tried connecting to port 5002, you would be told "connection refused" because no processes listens at this port. When you run an application that listens on port 5002, `netstat` will report it.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some confusion about what an 'open port' is. This is partly due to the informal way that everyone speaks about open ports.

With IP tables, you open a port for access (possibly with some restrictions etc.). That does not mean that there is anything behind it.

With `netstat -natp` you get a list of ports that a process actually listens to (state=`LISTEN`), where there is a session (`ESTABLISHED`) or where there is a session being closed (`CLOSE_WAIT`). We informally call ports in `LISTEN` "open ports" too, but this is not the same as in the context of `iptables`.

As a real-life analogy, `iptable` opens the ticket window, but `netstat` reports whether there is someone selling the tickets.